# how to deploy joomla website using xampp?

Tags: php, deployment, joomla, xampp

i have pre developed site ( using joomla ) 
i should make some editing to the database using xampp server 
should i install joomla ?
and when i enter 
localhost/project/index.php
i get this message

You may not be able to visit this page because of:

an out-of-date bookmark/favourite
a search engine that has an out-of-date listing for this site
a mistyped address
you have no access to this page
The requested resource was not found.
An error has occurred while processing your request.

Comment: You should deploy NOTHING with xampp. :) It is just insecure.

Comment: Can you clarify for me - in what format is the site you have previously developed? Is it a collection of .php files with a database dump ( .sql file) or is it an akeeba backup .jpa file? In general you just put the files in place, import your .sql file and edit the configuration.php file to reflect changes in path, url and database access details.  Sounds at the minute like your files are not in place withiin the /project/ folder under your webroot. If you   previously had a .htaccess file in place remove/rename that temporarily too.

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't need install it again. You did it before, just you need to install Xampp to run Apache and MySQL. Then copy your files in its htdocs folder in a certain folder (Like joomla). But pay attention that you must have a backup from your previous database. Otherwise, you need to install joomla again to create database and its tables.

Answer (score 0):

I used [AMPPS](http://www.ampps.com) to do the same. You can import your current installation of Joomla in Softaculous provided by AMPPS. AMPPS is also a WAMP Stack with auto-installation of more than 230 open-source scripts. All the site installed by AMPPS and imported manual installations will be managed by AMPPS.
(Note : Your config file of Joomla should be proper. Take bakup before importing)

If nothing works you can still install Joomla again as it is easy using AMPPS. Hope this helps. :)